# rosdep update for Fedora

Tags: ros, rosdep, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am configuring a user account on a Fedora machine to use ROS which is installed in the administer account.
When I use

$rosdep update

reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
... (couple of lines that I am not allowed to put here, they are online link)
Ignore legacy gbpdistro "groovy"
Ignore legacy gbpdistro "hydro"
Query rosdistro index ...
Add distro "groovy"
Add distro "hydro"
updated cache in /home/solmaz/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache

Then when I try

$ source /opt/ros/grooby/setup.bash

I get

CATKIN_SHELL=bash: Command not found.
Illegal variable name.

or when I try

$ export | grep ROS

I get

export: Command not found.

I need help in fixing this. Please explain your solution a bit in detail.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99156/rosdep-update-for-fedora/) by [Solmaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2778/solmaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you are not using bash? Maybe you're using sh or tcsh or zsh?

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1